# Retrieving current job for Azure ML v2

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Using the v2 Azure ML Python SDK (azure-ai-ml) how do I get an instance of the currently running job?

In v1 (azureml-core) I would do:

```py
from azureml.core import Run

run = Run.get_context()
if isinstance(run, Run):
    print("Running on compute...")
```

What is the equivalent on the v2 SDK?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent for the Run object in v2. Instead there is the MLFlow SDK for logging of metrics, saving and logging models, etc. You can use the v2 Python SDK to get a job by name, but it depends very much on what want to achieve. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve the author of the job, which is accessible through Job.creation_context.created_by.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a little more involved in v2 than in was in v1. The reason is that v2 makes a clear distinction between the control plane (where you start/stop your job, deploy compute, etc.) and the data plane (where you run your data science code, load data from storage, etc.).

Jobs can do control plane operations, but they need to do that with a proper identity that was explicitly assigned to the job by the user.

Let me show you the code how to do this first. This script creates an MLClient and then connects to the service using that client in order to retrieve the job's metadata from which it extracts the name of the user that submitted the job:

```py
# control_plane.py
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.identity import AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential
import os

def get_ml_client():
    uri = os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI"]
    uri_segments = uri.split("/")
    subscription_id = uri_segments[uri_segments.index("subscriptions") + 1]
    resource_group_name = uri_segments[uri_segments.index("resourceGroups") + 1]
    workspace_name = uri_segments[uri_segments.index("workspaces") + 1]
    credential = AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential()
    client = MLClient(
        credential=credential,
        subscription_id=subscription_id,
        resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
        workspace_name=workspace_name,
    )
    return client

ml_client = get_ml_client()
this_job = ml_client.jobs.get(os.environ["MLFLOW_RUN_ID"])
print("This job was created by:", this_job.creation_context.created_by)
```

As you can see, the code uses a special `AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential` to create the MLClient. Options that you would use locally (`AzureCliCredential` or `InteractiveBrowserCredential`) won't work for a remote job since you are not authenticated through `az login` or through the browser prompt on that remote run. For your credentials to be available on the remote job, you need to run the job with `user_identity`. And you need to retrieve the corresponding credential from the environment by using the `AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential` class.

So, how do you run a job with `user_identity`? Below is the yaml that will achieve it:

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandJob.schema.json
type: command
command: |
  pip install azure-ai-ml 
  python control_plane.py
code: code
environment: 
  image: library/python:latest
compute: azureml:cpu-cluster
identity:
  type: user_identity
```

Note the `identity` section at the bottom. Also note that I am lazy and install the azureml-ai-ml sdk as part of the job. In a real setting, I would of course create an environment with the package installed.

These are the valid settings for the identity type:

- `aml_token`: this is the default which will not allow you to access the control plane
- `managed` or `managed_identity`: this means the job will be run under the given managed identity (aka compute identity). This would be accessed in your job via `azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential`. Of course, you need to provide the chosen compute identity with access to the workspace to be able to read job information.
- `user_identity`: this will run the job under the submitting user's identity. It is to be used with the `azure.ai.ml.identity.AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential` credentials as shown above.

So, for your use case, you have 2 options:

1. You could run the job with `user_identity` and use the `AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential` class to create the MLClient
2. You could create the compute with a managed identity which you give access to the workspace and then run the job with `managed_identity` and use the `ManagedIdentityCredential` class to create the MLClient

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the very thorough answer. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I like the more clear distinction between control and data planes btw. Great work.

Answer (score 0):

The `azureml-core` belongs to a different module than the Azure ML Python SDK (`azure-ai-ml`). Therefore, you can specify it in the conda file and use it alongside v2.

I noticed this in the example for SDK v2: `Run.get_context()` is still usable.
[azure example v2](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/pipelines/1h_automl_in_pipeline/automl-text-classification-in-pipeline/register.py)

The test code for SDK v2 also uses `Run.get_context()`.
[test code of sdk v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/ml/azure-ai-ml/tests/test_configs/pipeline_jobs/serverless_compute/all_types/automl/components/src/register.py)

Answer (score 0):

assumming that we wish to access the `job_id` within the job/command code: know that there's a much simpler way, just use `os.getenv("AZUREML_RUN_ID")` to get the RUN_ID